# How to disable webview bouce effect in Blackberry 10 webworks application

Tags: webview, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing application for BB10 webworks. How I can remove webview bounce effect on blackberry 10 webworks application? I had tried using meta tag in index.html and adding preferences tag for webviewbounce effect in config.xml but none of them worked for me. I am not using BBui.js in my application so I can't use its tags to disable scroll.

thanks... <:)

Comment: Any solution on this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solved my issue using very simple css applied to my index.html as  below:
html, body{ height: 100%;  width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin:0px;}
No need of any meta or preference tags in index.html and config.xml respectively.

Comment: Please let me know if it was helpful for anyone and please do vote up :)